# Jenkins pipeline build github pull request

Tags: git, github, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

given that I use the pipeline plugin + all the github plugin are installed in jenkins, I'm struggled to checkout the current pull request that triggered the job in the pipeline script like this :

```
#!groovy

 node('master') {
       stage 'Checkout'

 checkout changelog: true, poll: true, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "origin/????"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[name: 'origin', url: 'git@github.com/project.git', credentialsId: 'github-id']]]

 }
```

but I don't find any way to get the current pull request branch from any env variable, maybe it's not that way to checkout the triggered branch ?

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
checkout scm
```

This is not just a syntactic simplification; it ensures that the repository revision checked out is exactly that of `Jenkinsfile` itself.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't use the multibranch pipeline but the simple one so 
checkout scm is not working there

Comment: You don't need to use multbranch pipeline to get this to work.  You just need to have a checked in Jenkinsfile and point to it in your pipeline job.

Comment: I would like to see an answer that doesn't require a Jenkinsfile.  There are certain implications that using a Jenksfile has right now since it's not fully supported by the full set of features that standard pipelines use.  Not all of us can make use of it.

Comment: this will not work when we have to checkout code at a particular location?

Comment: @user_9090 just use for example: `dir('subdir') {checkout scm}`

Comment: @BitwiseMan `checkout scm` _is_ available in non-multibranch jobs, but pending [JENKINS-36453](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36453) there is no guarantee that it is checking out the same revision as the `Jenkinsfile`—it might check out a newer branch tip.